# 'CMRESHandler' object has no attribute '_timer'

Tags: python, logging, flask, handler

When my application starts I am getting the exeption '' CMRESHandler 'object has no attribute' _timer '". The exception occurs when you start the CMRESHandler handler to send the logs to Elasticsearch.

The problem occurs only for local development but when I run the project with Docker the error does not occur.

```py
    handler_es = CMRESHandler(
        hosts=[{"host": KIBANA_SERVER, "port": 443}],
        auth_type=CMRESHandler.AuthType.NO_AUTH,
        use_ssl=True,
        es_index_name="authenticator_server",
        es_additional_fields={"project": "myproject", "environment": ENVIRONMENT},
    )
    handler_es.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(handler_es)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've had this problem too, I think it's a problem with your hostname.

Try execute:

`sudo hostname localhost`

And run the project again.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I need to re-run this command once in a while with no apparent reason (Django server goes down). How can I make the change permanent? thanks.

Comment: You can follow this tutorial https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-change-hostname-command/ works to me

Comment: Hi, everything is set-up as in the tutorial already, in spite of that my hostname is 'localhost.local' and keep getting the issue above. Unfortunately I am a mac user.

Comment: Got it :( https://support.apple.com/lt-lt/guide/mac-help/mchlp2322/mac works to me. Im a mac user too

Comment: Tried but didn't solve the issue. I'm running inside of PyCharm if that makes a difference.

Comment: :( So open a new question